# QTableView toggle setEditTriggers

Tags: toggle, qtableview

I have a checkbox to toggle the EDIT state of a QTableView.

```
void QPcbView::editToggle(bool editable)
{
    if(editable)
        this->setEditTriggers(QTableView::AllEditTriggers);
    else
        this->setEditTriggers(QTableView::NoEditTriggers);
}
```

This DOES work, but the view is not updated. Meaning when I toggle from editable to non-editable, the cell, that is currently selected stays editable, until it loses focus. How can I fix this behavior? I want my tableview to reflect the EDIT state instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Calling this->update() may work. Or you can check the checkbox value in the model data method.

Comment: Have you tried updateEditorData(), updateEditorGeometries(), or updateGeometries. There is also the reset method or setModel to the same model, but they are very inefficient.

Comment: I am a bloody QtNoob, so I don't get your second hint. Could you explain or show a little example? Thank you.

Comment: I tried all these:  
  this->updateEditorData();  
  this->update();  
  this->updateMicroFocus();  
  this->updateGeometry();  
  this->updatesEnabled();  
  this->updateEditorGeometries();

Comment: I just meant that there are additional methods for that class that change the view. this->updateEditorData(), this->updateEditorGeometries(), this->updateGeometries(), this->reset(), or this->setModel(this->model()). The last two methods reset and setModel are extremely inefficient because they have to reconnect everything and redraw the entire view. I mostly program in python and PySide, so I don't know if I can help you.

Comment: With ->reset it does update, but the column stays in a strange state it is not highlighted, but still somehow selected.  Pretty unusable for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: One other way is that you might be able to emit a signal from the model indicating something has changed. Try to find out how to emit signals for c++ and try to emit this->model()->layoutChanged.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html. It's a weird way of doing things, but it will probably work. That also might not be the right signal.